# SWIG - Java - Pass by reference int

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, swig

I have a simple function intReference

```
int intReference(int *intArray)
```

Where I am passing intArray by reference.

How do I set the interface file for SWIG such that it can do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This is the pattern I think you want:

**intReference.i**

```
%module intReference
%{
 extern int intReference(int intArray[]);
%}

%typemap(jtype) int intArray[] "int[]"
%typemap(jstype) int intArray[] "int[]"
%typemap(javain) int intArray[] "$javainput"
%typemap(jni) int intArray[] "jintArray"
%typemap(in) int intArray[] {
  jboolean isCopy;
  $1 = JCALL2(GetIntArrayElements, jenv, $input, &isCopy);
}
%typemap(freearg) int intArray[] {
  JCALL3(ReleaseIntArrayElements, jenv, $input, $1, 0);
}


extern int intReference(int intArray[]);
```

**intReference.c**

```
int intReference(int intArray[]) {
    intArray[0] = 42;
    return 43;
}
```

**Compiled with:**

```
swig -java *.i
javac *.java

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_60/
gcc -shared *.c -I "${JAVA_HOME}/include" -I "${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux" -o libintReference.so
```

**Test Code(java)**

```
System.loadLibrary("intReference");
int intArray[] = new int[1];
intReference.intReference(intArray);
System.out.println("intArray[0] = " + intArray[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an entire section about this in the [SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Java.html#Java_c_arrays). Depending on your needs, you may be able to just use built-in typemaps and SWIG directives.
For example,

`%include "arrays_java.i"
 %apply int[] {int *};`