# Passing byte[] from Java to C++

Tags: java, swig

I'm trying to pass a byte[] param with binary data and a string param from Java to C++ code using [SWIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG).

Here are my .i and .cpp files:

#### my_module.i

```
%module mymodule
%inline %{
   extern void compress_buffer_to_file(unsigned char *buffer, char *ofname);
%}
```

my_module.cpp

```
void compress_buffer_to_file(unsigned char *buffer, char *ofname){
   .........
}
```

The generated method in the Java wrapper:

```
public static void compress_buffer_to_file(SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char buffer, String ofname) {
   my_moduleJNI.compress_buffer_to_file(SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char.getCPtr(buffer), ofname);
}
```

How can I define a .i file that will generate a Java wrapper that will let me pass byte[] instead of SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char to the compress_buffer_to_file method or alternatively? How do I associate an existing byte[] on the Java side with a SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char?

I've tried to use typemap with no success.

Comment: I think my answer here replacing int with byte, should work http://stackoverflow.com/a/33488560/5171540

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want SWIG to perform a conversion between Java and C++ types, namely

1. Java `byte[]` to `unsigned char *` and
2. `String` to `char *`.

The general tools for such conversions are SWIG [typemaps](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps). Conveniently, many are already provided by SWIG and simply need to be *applied*. Have a look at the [Java typemap documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Java_typemaps).

The latter conversion (`String` to `char *`) is done automatically by SWIG (using predefined typemaps that match `char *` arguments).

### Using predefined typemaps

A standard conversion very similar to what you want (`byte[]` to `char *`) is handled by the "`char * BYTE`" typemaps defined in the file [`various.i`](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/java/various.i). To use it, all you need to do is add

```
%include various.i
%apply char *BYTE { char *buffer_variable_name };
```

at the top of the swig interface file, where `buffer_variable_name` is the *name* of the variable in the function argument (typemaps can be matched by name). For details, see the general [typemap documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps) and the [Java typemap documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Java_typemaps).

However, this is not exactly what you want, since your function takes an `unsigned char *`. If you can use `java.nio.Buffer` instead of `byte[]` on the Java side (which needs to be allocated via `allocateDirect`), there is a different set of typemaps predefined in `various.i` that can be used via

```
%apply unsigned char *NIOBUFFER { unsigned char *buffer_variable_name };
```

### Writing your "own" typemaps

In your case you want essentially the same as the provided "`char * BYTE`" typemaps, but for functions taking `unsigned char *`. So you can just copy these from [`various.i`](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/java/various.i) to a new file `ubyte.i` and tweak them slightly:

ubyte.i

```
%typemap(jni) unsigned char *UBYTE "jbyteArray"
%typemap(jtype) unsigned char *UBYTE "byte[]"
%typemap(jstype) unsigned char *UBYTE "byte[]"
%typemap(in) unsigned char *UBYTE {
  $1 = (unsigned char *) JCALL2(GetByteArrayElements, jenv, $input, 0); 
}

%typemap(argout) unsigned char *UBYTE {
  JCALL3(ReleaseByteArrayElements, jenv, $input, (jbyte *) $1, 0); 
}

%typemap(javain) unsigned char *UBYTE "$javainput"

/* Prevent default freearg typemap from being used */
%typemap(freearg) unsigned char *UBYTE ""
```

Use these in the same way, by adding at the top of your swig interface file:

```
%include ubyte.i
%apply unsigned char *UBYTE { unsigned char *buffer_variable_name };
```

Using these predefined typemaps as a basic example, and reading the docs, you can then start writing your own custom typemaps if you need to.

Hope this helps.